# Populate array through table values

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

The title should be more specific, I know, but the question is too elaborated to even describe in one title itself... I'm having troubles to pass certain amount of values into one array to post via AJAX.

## Here's the HTML code with a foreach loop inside the table

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Select</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Name</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Situation</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Bill</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Date Limit</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Value of Bill</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Own Value</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Responsable Name</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <?php
     foreach ($result as $value) {
        echo '<tr style="text-align: center;">
              <td><input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" value="'. $value['VALUEBILL'] .'" class="check_list"></input>
              <input style="display: none;" type="checkbox" checked="true" value="'. $value['IDTRANSACTION'] .'" name="numControle"></td>
              <td>'. utf8_encode($value['NAME']) .'</td>
              <td>'. $value['SITUATION'] .'</td>
              <td>'. $value['BILL'] .'</td>
              <td>'. $value['DATELIMIT'] .'</td>
              <td>'. $value['VALUEBILL'] .'</td>
              <td>'. $value['OWNVALUE'] .'</td>
              <td>'. utf8_encode($value['RESPONSABLENAME']) .'</td>
              </tr>';
     }

  ?>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

For a better understading, I have one `jQuery` script wich will sum all bills selected and give the result of all of them together, taking the checked `$value['VALUEBILL']` checkboxes.

#### Here's the jQuery script to get and sum all checked checkboxes values.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   update();
});
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
   update();
})
function update(){
   var amount2 = 0;
   $('.check_list').each(function () {
      if (this.checked) {
        amount2 += Number($(this).val());
          checked_boxes ++;
      }
   $("input[name=amount]").val("$"+amount2.toFixed(2));
});
```

### Here's the form where the script sum all values and input:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="purchases" novalidate>
  <h4 style="margin-top: -5px;">Total:</h4>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount2" name="amount" value="" disabled="">
  <button type="submit">Send Payment</button>
</form>
```

***I pointed the code to a better understanding on what I'm doing and to let you know about what the main problem is***

**Q:** So, what do you need, because is not clear at all?

Take note inside the `foreach` loop, it has an ocult `checkbox` with the value of `$value['IDTRANSACTION']`, this is what I need to send aswell with the other `checkbox`... The first `checkbox` have the value of the bill, and the second, the `ID` of transaction, which each one have its unique value, and it's **extremely** important to account all those bills.

So my question is:

- How do I check this box aswell when the first `checkbox` is checked? (I tried a few `jQuery` codes, but they checked ALL of them in a row when I checked the first one, I need to check only the one which is checked, and not the others that `foreach` provide);
- After getting the first issue sorted out, I need to populate one `array` inside the `form` to send in one AJAX post (which is already ready and working properly) to get all the `checkboxes` values with the `ID's` of each one.

That's it... I'm sorry for the long question, but I needed to provide all the info I could so you could understand what I'm trying to do.

Cheers!